# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Not that I want to exactly, I just noticed there is no option to edit [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507384/what-is-the-grammarical-topic-of-this-sentence):

[image: why no edit?]

I do have the edit privilege as of writing - what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was probably a pending edit. I think the mobile templates don't show that there's a pending edit, just hiding the edit text entirely.

Comment: That's it, thanks. Looking at the edit history confirms an edit pending round about that time: https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/507384/revisions